# How to see Java threads from Remote Desktop Connection Client. Ctrl-break not working

Tags: java, macos, remote-desktop

I am connecting to a Windows XP machine via Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection Client, version 2.0.0 Beta 3, running on a Mac. On the Windows machine there is a Java console running, where I want to send a Ctrl-Break so I can see the Java threads running.

According to the RDC help, Alt/Option-F3 is break, but Ctrl-Opt-F3 and various other combinations do not have an effect.

Any ideas on how to send a Ctrl-Break?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've updated the question title to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Hit CTRL+ALT+END instead.

Comment: Excellent! I was looking just for that combination! +1 to you, sir :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this help anyone, but i was trying to debug a vba project and had this same problem. That is how i ended up here to begin with. I used the "On-Screen Keyboard" in Accessories->Accessibility

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Where is Accessories?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the options given above but none worked for me.  Eventually managed to access break the VBA code execution with:

```
fn + Esc
```

For reference I'm using:
Macbook Air with OS X 10.7.2
Via Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac version 2.1.0
Accessing Windows 7 Enterprise running on VMWARE

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> doesn't work on a macbook: no <kbd>End</kbd> key.  The "On-Screen Keyboard" did the trick though.  Thanks!

Comment: How'd you get the "On-Screen Keyboard"?  I don't see it in any of the menus in Microsoft Remote Desktop Client.  I should also say I'm using a non-Mac USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Still would like to see a way to send Ctrl-Break from a Mac Book Pro to a Windows machine via RDP for Mac.  Trying the default key assignment (Option-F3) doesn't work and re-assigning the key doesn't seem to work either.  If anybody has successfully sent a Ctrl-Break using the RDP client on a Mac, I'd love to hear how you did it.  Google searches have been fruitless so far.

Comment: I would like to know this as well!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to send a BREAK (which on my laptop is FN+Page Down) - this was to break VBA code running in Excel. When RDPing from a Mac I used fn+F14 - got this via trial and error.